# Place more than 1000 images in a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios

My question is that i have to get more then 1000 images in UITableView from NSURL what could i do .. i have to run smooth running but i also use `async` classes to get but its doesn't give me a good performance what i want. I also use `ASIHTTPRequest` classes to load the images faster but can't. Please tell me some techniques how its possible. then images not more then 1500 and not less then 1000.

Please recommend me some code or some guide how could i do it ? Its not very hectic for me to do that smoothly.

Currently I am fetching images from my webserver via `NSURL Request`..

Thanks.

Comment: Please mention what do you mean smooth? It doesn't scroll smooth or loading images performance isn't good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of these libraries works fine for me.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache

Comment: awesome solution SDWebImage its great love to see this public library

Answer (score 2):

If your scrolling isn't smooth enough - you don't use lazy loading properly.

Check here [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple.
They have pretty good example in WWDC videos (available if you have developer connection account) about improving UI performance. They dig into lazy loading pretty well in this video.